# How to pad with one and zeroes to width 12?

Tags: r, string, number-formatting

I have data which looks like :

```
df <- read.table(text = "col
921103
142106
12095769
11102
32456", header = TRUE)
```

I would like pad with one `1` and `zeroes` to width 12 :

```
col
100000921103
100000142106
100012095769
100000011102
100000032456
```

Any insight is helpful!Thank you.

Comment: Assuming none of your initial figures are higher than 10^11 you can simply add 100000000000 (10^11) to all initial numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sprintf` with the pattern `"1%011d"` to get a 1 first and the number padded with 0s to match width of 11.

```r
df$col <- sprintf("1%011d", df$col)

df
#            col
# 1 100000921103
# 2 100000142106
# 3 100012095769
# 4 100000011102
# 5 100000032456
```

---

Or with `paste0` + `str_pad`:

```r
library(stringr)
df$col <- paste0('1', str_pad(df$col, width = 11, pad = "0"))
```

Comment: I don't know why i didn't think of it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding:

```
df$colnew <- df$col + 10^11
# df
#        col       colnew
# 1   921103 100000921103
# 2   142106 100000142106
# 3 12095769 100012095769
# 4    11102 100000011102
# 5    32456 100000032456
```

**Note:** this would fail if we add 10^12, to avoid we will need to convert the column into a string.

Comment: Love how basic this solution is.

Comment: Yeah, but I'd still go with strpadding/pasting see note.